# Flask: 405 "Method Not Allowed" error when trying to POST to a endpoint even though it's allowed on the route

Tags: javascript, html, flask, cors, http-status-code-405

Im Trying to create new website with tensorflow and Flask. I'm created model about eye diseases. I'm trying to get image with  html. After that, predict that image with my model and see results on website.
Here is my Python Code (Im Turkish thats why some texts are Turkish.):

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import base64
import io
import os
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import Dense
from tensorflow.python.keras.models import load_model

os.environ['CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES'] = '0'

model = tf.keras.models.load_model("goz.model")

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/predict', methods=["POST"])
def predict():
    response = request.get_json()
    data_str = response['image']
    point = data_str.find(',')
    base64_str = data_str[point:]

    image = base64.b64decode(base64_str)       
    img = Image.open(io.BytesIO(image))

    if(img.mode!='RGB'):
        img = img.convert("RGB")
    
    CATEGORIES = ["Cataract", "Diabetic_retinopathy", "gluacoma", "normal" ]
    img = img.resize((180, 180))

    x = img.img_to_array(img)
    x = np.expand_dims(x, 0)
  
    preds = model.predict(img, model)
    score = tf.nn.softmax(preds[0])
    result = "Bu fotograf su hastaliga benziyor: {} yuz uzerinden su kadar eminim: {:.2f}.".format(CATEGORIES[np.argmax(score)], 100*np.max(score))

    return jsonify(result)

@app.after_request
def add_headers(response):
    response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
    response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type,Authorization')


    return response


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0')
```

But when i submit image this is happening:

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hdA52.png)

Here mentioned codes in Error (writed with HTML and Javascript):
Line 172-190:

```
function predictImage(image) {
  fetch("/predict", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(image)
  })
    .then(resp => {
      if (resp.ok)
        resp.json().then(data => {
          displayResult(data);
        });
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log("An error occured", err.message);
      window.alert("Oops! Something went wrong.");
    });
}
```

Line 123-140:

```
function submitImage() {
 console.log("submit");

  if (!imageDisplay.src || !imageDisplay.src.startsWith("data")) {
    window.alert("Please select an image before submit.");
    return;
  }

  loader?.classList?.remove("hidden");
  imageDisplay.classList.add("loading");

  predictImage(imageDisplay.src);
}
```

Line 53:

```
          <input type="button" value="Submit" class="button" onclick="submitImage();" />
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! I think your problem is related to something about your configuration not included in this question.  The tensorflow stuff is unrelated to your core problem and could be removed from your question for simplicity. Your real problem is you're getting an 405 "Method Not Allowed" error on your /predict POST request and that should be told clearly in your question and not just in a linked screenshot. I have a guess on how to fix it, but figuring it out could have been easier. I'll post that as an answer though. Godspeed!

Comment: one more comment: The core error message, `405 Method Not Allowed`  should be in the question's title. Your current title really says nothing about the problem. Try to make the title very clear in the future. I am editing your question to correct this 

Answer (score 0):

I think your `/predict` "POST" request is being sent to whatever other server is serving your HTML and not to Flask. What is serving your HTML and what is listening on port 5500? I don't think it's Flask?

Flask by default listens on port 5000 but you're screenshot shows a POST to port 5500. You should be sending the POST to wherever Flask is listening. Also you should be seeing some message in the Flask console like `"POST /predict HTTP/1.1"`. If Flask isn't showing anything when you make the POST, as I suspect, then that means Flask isn't receiving it and something else is returning that error.

So to fix your problem, assuming Flask is on port 5000, change:

```
fetch("/predict", {
...
```

to:

```
fetch("http://127.0.0.1:5000/predict", {
...
```

If my theory is correct that'll ensure that Flask actually receives the POST. Let me know if that fixes it for you.

If the above is all true then it's worth noting that because your HTML/JS's origin is `127.0.0.1:5500` but Flask is on `127.0.0.1:5000`, you're now making a cross-origin CORS request since ports are included with the origin.  However, I just made a cross-origin request to [a simplified version of your code](https://gist.github.com/varenc/28c5a8eb15f483dc07a431d0069ccd5e) and your Flask app correctly responds with all the right CORS headers so it should still work! (the presence of those CORS headers also hinted to me that you might be serving the HTML from a different port/origin)

Comment: First, thanks for your help. But there are some problems. When I open website it will happens:
https://imgur.com/a/vBFgrS8
But when I open website with live server it will happen: (127.0.0.1:5000)
https://imgur.com/a/aMzk8Z9
All my code files in 1 folder 
Also I'm sorry about title I'm new in this website.

Comment: Are you sure Flask is running and listening on port 5000? Makes sure it is.  You could have your Flask app respond with a simple "hello world" on the `/` route as a way to make it easy to check. You could also change the last line of your file to `app.run(debug=True, host='127.0.0.1',port=5000)` to make very sure where it's running. Also one of your errors looks like you might be trying to evaluate your python code as javascript in the browser. good luck!

Comment: Some more thoughts: You could try serving the javascript and HTML from Flask.  That'll simplify things for you a lot! Also I think you'd benefit from a "Build your first Flask Website" tutorial. When developing try to cut down your project to the bare minimum and test every part as it goes along. For example, make sure your XHR POST requests work before writing anything that uses tensorflow. This tutorial looked decent and shows how you can serve HTML and JS from Flask directly: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-make-a-web-application-using-flask-in-python-3